# How to see history of files downloaded by uGet?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, uget

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 - a fresh installation.

I have installed **uGet** and I want to see the history of the files I have downloaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this one. The answer is in uGet itself. It only a question of specifying historical fields enough per category